# Why does webkit2png not work? ImportError: cannot import name init_qtgui

Tags: python

Why does webkit2png not work?

```
from webkit2png import WebkitRenderer, init_qtgui

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/screen/test4.py", line 1, in <module>
    from webkit2png import WebkitRenderer, init_qtgui
ImportError: cannot import name init_qtgui

import webkit2png
from pprint import pprint
pprint(dir(webkit2png))

['WebkitRenderer',
 '__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'webkit2png']
```

I am trying to take a screen shot of a Page.  Is there a library that actually works?
I am using ubuntu 12.04.